# Turning off resizable rhandsontable

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I am using rhandsontable to create a table for the user to edit. I noticed that if you drag the box on the bottom right past the last boxes, you can resize the dataframes. Is there an option or solution to be able to turn off that the resizable dataframe?

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

server = (function(input, output, session) {

output$hot = renderRHandsontable({
    DF = data.frame(val = 1:10, bool = TRUE, big = LETTERS[1:10],
                small = letters[1:10],
                dt = seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", length.out = 10),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

rhandsontable(DF, readOnly = TRUE, width = 550, height = 300) %>%
  hot_col("val", readOnly = FALSE)
  })
})

ui = (fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput("hot")
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: add code of your rhandsontable  app

Comment: I added one of the examples listed from the introduction page. All of the examples seems to allow the ability to resize.

Comment: its looks like bug in handsontable.js exist not only in rshiny https://docs.handsontable.com/0.27.0/demo-read-only.html